# Remove the checked element from the page

Tags: php, jquery

I have this script thats send a post via jquery.form addon:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#submit_btn').on('click', function(e)            { 
            $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#preview',
        success:  afterSuccess //call function after 
        }); 
    });
});        
function afterSuccess()
{
$('#imageform').resetForm();
$('.ImgStatus').appendTo('.img');
}
```

and gets a html respond.

```
<div id="<?php echo $RandNumber; ?>" class="ImgStatus">
<input id="<?php echo $RandNumber; ?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $RandNumber; ?>" />                              
<img src='upload/<?php echo $actual_image_name; ?>' class='preview'>
</div>
```

And what I'm trying to do is to remove the div that corresponds to the checkbox ID, when the delete button is clicked. And also to send a $_POST to a php page with the checked divs. Until now I have something like this but When I press the button its not removing the element...

```
$("#clickme").click(function(e){    
var selected = $(".img input:checked").map(function(i,el){return el.name;}).get();   
$(selected).remove();      
});
```

jsfiddle.net/aHr6v/3

Comment: try to see how many elements are in the `selected` variable

Comment: I put up a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aHr6v/3/ , with an alert that shows exact the result I'm getting from the page. I just have to found a way to remove the the div that has the same id with the checkbox name.

Comment: check the answers bellow, and you will get what you wanted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
$(selected).remove();
```

To

```
$('#'+selected).remove();
```

**Edit:** Or To (to remove all selected divs)

```
$.each(selected, function(){
    $('#' + this).remove();
});
```

Comment: This will only do one... I will edit my post to do more than 1

Comment: Only after you posted the option to remove all div's I realize I needed that option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select the parent of the selected input field (the div), and remove it like this:

```
$("#clickme").click(function(e){  
    var selected = $(".img input:checked").parent();
    $(selected).remove();
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aHr6v/5/

Answer (score 1):

check this: http://jsfiddle.net/aHr6v/6/

Based on what you said in your comment, I added the following line which search the div by its id and remove it

```
$("div#"+selected).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#clickme").click(function (e) {
    $('div.img input:checked').closest('div').remove();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aHr6v/8/).

This looks at all inputs that are checked, finds the closest parent ancestor that's a `div` and then removes that/those elements from the DOM.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: Why not use the more semantic `:has`? `$('div.img').has('input:checked').remove()`

Comment: Because I don't think it adds anything to the readability, mainly.

Comment: It is as readable (more readable I'd argue, since there's less characters) and is more efficient since it doesn't require the extra reverse tree traversal.

Comment: No, [it doesn't seem to be more efficient](http://jsperf.com/does-has-help-or-impede).

Answer (score 1):

`selected` is an array. What you want to do is pass one or more elements of that array as a selector:

```
$.each(selector, function(){
    $('#' + this).remove();
})
```